# How can I program a geometric spline for the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

Can anyone explain the logic behind drawing a spline line on the canvas? I understand the basic geometric logic behind splines but I'm struggling to understand how to implement this programmatically. I've looked at a fair few examples (http://www.rgraph.net/ and http://scaledinnovation.com/analytics/splines/aboutSplines.html) but none have enough commenting in the source code to see exactly what needs to be done.

I don't want to go ahead and adapt a working spline example because I wish to understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "understand the logic behind [splines]" you mean the mathematical logic behind splines, you might check out this great course on splines taught at the University of Oslo:

The course by Michael S. Floater has some amazing study guides that are readable, informative and complete.

The first session has a great explanation of why splines are better at connecting points than other curves like Bezier/Quadratic.

The session goes on the explain the logical and mathematical basis of splines.

http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT5340/v07/undervisningsmateriale/kap1.pdf

The rest of the sessions build on the reasoning behind splines:

http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT5340/v07/undervisningsmateriale/